# What does `numpy.array(1, dtype=np.int32)` do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am following this tutorial: [Train a Deep Q Network with TF-Agents](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial.ipynb). There is a line of code that says

```
action = np.array(1, dtype=np.int32)
```

When I try to inspect `action` in Visual Studio Code. Let it be the watch, debug console, or hovering, it throws an error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

Looking at [the document of numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) I only find examples that look like

```
action = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)
```

So the first object is a already a python array. When I pass `np.array([1], dtype=np.int32)` to the debug console, I can inspect the return value without an error.

The next line in the tutorial that uses the `action` variable does not throw any error, but returns a value, as expected.

So it does not look like a bug to me, as the code seems to do the job. But I do not understand it. Why can I not inspect that `action` variable? Initially I thought that it would be an endless array (virtually) which VSCode had trouble to enumerate. so I thought to inspect `action[0]` therefore. But this too throws the same error. When I try `len(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32))` it shows `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. `np.size(np.array(1, dtype=np.int32))` returns value `1`. Then I thought to use `np.append(action, 2)` which returned `array([1, 2])`, as one would expect. `len(np.append(action, 2))` also behaves as one would expect by returning the value `2`.

So how come I cannot take a look at `action` or `action[0]` or `len(action)` initially ?

Comment: It creates a zero dimensional array. Probably VS code debugger doesn't know how to handle it. See https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0027-zero-rank-arrarys.html

Comment: While inspecting an object with the IDE can be nice, you should also be comfortable inspecting the object in the Python iteractive session itself.  Or as many us do, in an `ipython` session.  `np.array(1)` is a valid numpy array, with a `dtype`, `shape` and `ndim`.  Indexing is a bit tricky, though logical once you understand shapes (using `arr[()]` or `arr.item()`).

Comment: Alright. Pointing out it is a zero dimensional array is really hepful! Thanks @ayhan. By the documentation I could see that the value of the array can be obtained using `action.item()` or `action[()]`, in this case. Thanks @hpaulj for pointing that part out!